# block rows for select query till update query is done its job

Tags: hibernate, oracle11g

I came across a strange scenario in Oracle. one client is trying to get few records with permission option "select for update"(rows will be locked till the transaction complete). Before first client commit the transaction,  another client can also try to access the rows with read only permission.  is it possible to block the rows for second client which were blocked by the first client till transaction commit. Pls guide me. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle, readers never block writers and writers never block readers.  So another session will always be able to read the current committed state of a row regardless of what the update process is doing.

If you want to prevent the rows from being read, you would need to code some additional locking logic.  The reader could also do a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` with or without a `WAIT` so that it would block until the writer's transaction commits.  You could also build locking logic using a different table.  You could build some logic where the writer updates a row in a different table indicating that the update process is underway and all the reader processes could read that row.